# export tableau to csv including measures

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I have a tableau workbook that was given to me. I open it and I see everything there.

I want to export the data to CSV *including the measures* which are a bunch of sums. Right now the measures are in the right 4 'colummns' but not in the column shelve.

How do I get it out into CSV format clean so that I can push it through R. This is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep things clean, and save processing power, what I like to do in cases like this is drag all the dimensions and measures to Detail, instead of rows or columns.

I choose the Bar chart manually first. That way, Tableau won't waste time processing a visualization for the data. But the data will still be there, you can right click on the "phantom" chart, and select View Data. All is there. What is also there is an Export button, that will export to a csv.

If you have Tableau Server, you can use tabcmd to export this data to a csv.

```
tabcmd export "worksheet-name" --csv
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. Tableau allows you to export "data" or "crosstab." It sounds like you're looking for the raw data version here.

The most obvious would be to use the Worksheet menu and select "Export > Data."

If the worksheet is published to Tableau Server, just add ".csv" at the end of the browser URL.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have some more details. For example, whether you want to export the aggregated measures (the sums) or the underlying data rows that contribute to those sums.

There are many ways to export data, but you can start by using the Worksheet->Export->Data menu to export the data displayed on the current worksheet.